# Is there a product available that is pre-gelatinized starch and what product name is it sold with?

Tags: thickening, starch

I am trying to make packets of instant pudding that do not need heating, in order to thicken the mix to form a cold dessert. Some sanity has to be found in my kitchen, as most foods are home cooked because of my allergies.

I have attempted to test rice paper and tapioca flour (Australian brand and Chinese or East Asian product), potato starch, and puffed amaranth breakfast cereal, thinking that some value or gel might result from my efforts.  (It has not.)

Inquiries regarding pre-gelatinised products result in blunt dismissal, as those products here in Australia are reserved exclusively for medical reasons to celiacs or patients with problems swallowing, and supply is restricted to local chemists.

Is the supply of these products restricted by requirements for a doctor's prescription? If not, how or where can I obtain them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on what others above have said, Ultratex is tapioca starch, specifically tapioca maltodextrin. I imagine maltodextrin must be available in Australia. Occasionally health food stores sell it.

If you go to khymos.org and search for the downloadable PDF 'Textures: A hydrocolloid recipe collection,' you will find within a whole bunch of different thickening products (both trade names and chemical names). Alternatively, simonjohnson.com.au carries the *Texturas* line of products from Albert and Ferran Adria, which includes a variety of thickening and gelling agents.

Comment: Hey Daniel - sorry, but this isn't right! They are both derived from tapioca, but tapioca maltodextrin is a different thing entirely. Tapioca maltodextrin thickens oils, not water-based liquids. It is used to do things like make powdered olive oil. (There are so many modified food starches, you have to be really sure to get the right one for a given application).

Comment: I have searched at khymos.org and obtained 'Textures: A hydrocolloid recipe collection' thanks daniel. Also found some other hints that will help for my ice cream recipe. In this second response it seems that tapioca starch is not what I know as tapioca flour? If the tapioca maltodextrin able to assist in emulsification then, thus making it unsuitable in the application defined in the original question?

Comment: I found the 'Textures: A hydrocolloid recipe collection' educational and useful for a solution to my problem and the ice machine will solve the formation of a carvable soft ice cream. Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, what you want is UltraTex-3 (or possibly the 8 or UltraSperse variants), from National Starch. Willpowder carries them: http://www.willpowder.net/tapioca.html

You can make something very much like instant pudding from just about any liquid using this stuff, and it can be cold. No heating required. Works best with a stick blender.

Comment: Michael at Herbivoracious thanks for your answer but I'm a bit far away in Australia. There is no indication the supplier has any current contacts here and I am unable to determine by referring to the list if Australia is included.

Comment: @gypsybird - they say they list countries they ship to in the PayPal check out process, so you could check and see if you are on the list by starting check out (you wouldn't have to finish).

Comment: I have made a search and found two providers here in Australia. The Red spoon in Strathfield near Sydney and the Melbourne Food Ingredient Depot which has an added item of Icecream and Sorbet stabiliser. Sorry Michael at Herbivoracious, no Ultra-Tex-3, 8 or UltraSperse appears at either website but thanks for all your help

Answer (score 2):

Instant Clear Jel is your answer!  It's a modified corn starch that gelatinizes even in cold liquid.  It is very similar to what they use in the instant pudding mixes at the store.  They sell it on Amazon as well as another site that can be purchased in bulk.  Just make sure to buy the **Instant**, otherwise you'll have regular pudding.

[http://www.amazon.com/Instant-Clear-Jel-1-lb/dp/B00015UC52](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00015UC52)
http://www.theingredientstore.com/generalstore/product_details/310.htm (even comes with a recipe)

Comment: Nick Cessac thanks for your answer but I'm a bit far away in Australia. The supplier stated on the site that his current contacts are certain countries and my country is not on the list.

Comment: I have made a search and found two providers here in Australia. The Red spoon in Strathfield near Sydney and the Melbourne Food Ingredient Depot which has an added item of Icecream and Sorbet stabiliser. Both suppliers have calcium lactate, lethicin and maltodextrin and methyl cellulose. Many other items are also available. Now I just need to obtain enough info to use these products in a proper and constructive method? Sorry Nick Cessac, no Instant Clear Jel appears at either website but thanks for all your help.

Answer (score -1):

> I am trying to make packets of instant pudding that do not need heating, in order to thicken the mix to form a cold dessert.

In case it does not have to be "instant" you could also use flax or chia seeds as a wholesome alternative. However, depending on your desired thickness thickening might take quite some while.

Comment: Since the OP (and your quote!) specifies that the starch *does* have to be instant, this doesn't seem particularly helpful.